# How to use onSavedInstanceState() to save altered image when changing orientation or switching screens

Tags: java, android, android-activity, orientation

I have created a craps application that is nearly complete, but I cannot get the dice images to save when the changing orientation of the screen. I have been messing around with the `onSavedInstanceState()` method and cannot figure out how to achieve this. I have also noticed that when I switch to a new activity screen (the "how to play" screen) and then back to the home screen, none of the previous activity has been saved even though it is saved when changing orientation.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    // declarations
    private Button button;
    private ImageView dice1Image;
    private ImageView dice2Image;
    private TextView roll;
    private TextView point;
    private TextView winTotal;
    private TextView lostTotal;
    private TextView results;

    int winNumber1 = 7;
    int winNumber2 = 11;
    int loseNumber1 = 2;
    int loseNumber2 = 3;
    int loseNumber3 = 12;

    int rounds = 0;
    int rollTotal = 0;
    int pointValue = 0;
    int winsCounter = 0;
    int loseCounter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dice1Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDie01);
        dice2Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDie02);
        roll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRollTotal);
        point = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPoint);
        winTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWonTotal);
        lostTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLostTotal);
        results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);
        results.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.howToPlayButton);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int pointValue = savedInstanceState.getInt("POINT_VALUE");
            int rollTotal = savedInstanceState.getInt("ROLL_TOTAL");
            int winsCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt("WINS_COUNTER");
            int loseCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt("LOSE_COUNTER");
            String result = savedInstanceState.getString("RESULTS");
            int dice1 =  savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE_1", R.id.imageViewDie01);
            int dice2 =  savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE_2", R.id.imageViewDie02);

            roll.setText(String.valueOf(rollTotal));
            point.setText(String.valueOf(pointValue));
            winTotal.setText(String.valueOf(winsCounter));
            lostTotal.setText(String.valueOf(loseCounter));
            results.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        }
```

I realize that the `dice1` and `dice2` variables are never used. That is where I am stuck. I am not sure of the best approach to saving an image. Here is the `onSavedInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
        // killed and restarted.
        String result = results.getText().toString();
        savedInstanceState.putInt("POINT_VALUE", pointValue);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("ROLL_TOTAL", rollTotal);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("WINS_COUNTER", winsCounter);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("LOSE_COUNTER", loseCounter);
        savedInstanceState.putString("RESULTS", result);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("DIE_1", d1);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("DIE_2", d2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
        int pointValue = savedInstanceState.getInt("POINT_VALUE");
        int rollTotal = savedInstanceState.getInt("ROLL_TOTAL");
        int winsCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt("WINS_COUNTER");
        int loseCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt("LOSE_COUNTER");
        String result = savedInstanceState.getString("RESULTS");
        int dice1 =  savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE_1");
        int dice2 =  savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE_2");
    }
```

The `d1` and `d2` variables are used in my `rollDice()` method which set a value to the dice images like this:

```
// set values for dice images
        if(dice1 == 1) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
            d1 = 1;
        }....
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems okay, please elaborate your issue.

Comment: When I change orientation of the screen in the middle of a game, the dice image activity is not saved and reverts back to the default images. The other issue is that when leaving the home page during the middle of a game (IE: going to the instructions page and then back to the home page) all of the activities revert back to the default value of 0. I am not sure why the `savedInstance State` is functioning correctly (except for the dice images) when flipping orientation but not when switching between pages.

Comment: Also, the result string does not save `if (savedInstanceState != null) { String result = savedInstanceState.getString("RESULTS"); results.setText(String.valueOf(result)); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of trying to save the images I just re-wrote them to display based on the dice rolled saved integer.

Inside of my `onCreate()`:

```
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
```

Here is my `onSavedInstanceState()`:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
        // killed and restarted.
        savedInstanceState.putInt("POINT_VALUE", pointValue);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("ROLL_TOTAL", rollTotal);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("WINS_COUNTER", winsCounter);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("LOSE_COUNTER", loseCounter);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("DIE_1", d1);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("DIE_2", d2);
    } // end onSavedInstanceState
```

And here is my `onRestoreInstanceState()`:

```
@Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
        pointValue = savedInstanceState.getInt("POINT_VALUE");
        rollTotal = savedInstanceState.getInt("ROLL_TOTAL");
        winsCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt("WINS_COUNTER");
        loseCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt("LOSE_COUNTER");
        d1 =  savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE_1");
        d2 =  savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE_2");

        roll.setText(String.valueOf(rollTotal));
        point.setText(String.valueOf(pointValue));
        winTotal.setText(String.valueOf(winsCounter));
        lostTotal.setText(String.valueOf(loseCounter));

        if(d1 == 1) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
        }
        else if(d1 == 2) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
        }
        else if(d1 == 3) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
        }
        else if(d1 == 4) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
        }
        else if(d1 == 5) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
        }
        else if(d1 == 6) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
        }

        if(d2 == 1) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
        }
        else if(d2 == 2) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
        }
        else if(d2 == 3) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
        }
        else if(d2 == 4) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
        }
        else if(d2 == 5) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
        }
        else if(d2 == 6) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
        }
    } // end onRestoreInstanceState method
```

This resolves the images reverting back to the default images when the screen is rotated by reassigning a value to each drawable image, then using the saved dice values to determine which image should appear. Not sure if this is the most optimal solution but it solves my problem.